# Svelte 3.52 and Typescript

Tags: svelte-3

Does anyone know how to run **Typescript** with Svelte 3.52?

It was bat file, but it wasn't anymore. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should use svelte-ts instead svelte.

`npm create vite@latest myapp -- --template svelte-ts`